# How to check if WMI is broken or not?

Tags: windows-server-2008, wmi

I'm looking for a way to check whether WMI is running properly on a Windows Server 2008 machine. I'd prefer to do this by running a command. Is there any?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

or just do somethig like this at an elevated prompt

wmic os

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. When WMI is down, it gives an error message and I can catch that pattern.

Answer (score 8):

WMIDiag is a good place to start.

**WMI Diagnosis Utility**
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff404265.aspx

**WMIDiag download**
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7684